# How to delete duplicated brushes in paint mode

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying to get my head around Blender, I do like it allot but it's a bit daunting.

I've had some issues in Texture Paint mode getting the brushes to work.  I finally got a brush to work but in the mean time I've created a bunch of duplicates that are non functional or as I like to say "empty brushes" that are just taking up space and confuse me a little.  Even the default brush doesn't work but brush #9 (duplicate) functions as it should.  I've searched hi and low for a simple explanation on how to delete unwanted brushes but every Blender forum I search on points me to unhelpful articles.

Thanks for the assist!
Richard

Comment: You can do it in the Outliner > Orphan Datas, but there should be a easier way

Comment: Don't know where to look in the Outliner for Orphan Data's I've right clicked all over that area and don't find that in any slide out menu.  I'm thinking this shouldn't be this hard but apparently it is.

Comment: In the Outliner, display the Orphan Data, then under Brush find the new brushes you've created and right click > Delete: https://zupimages.net/up/23/26/i5qm.jpg not convenient I agree but I don't know if there's another way

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  OK, after much sloothing I got it figured out.

Go to the side panel and under the Brush settings choose this menu, click on that and up comes all the brushes. Under the Operations drop down choose to Delete Brush Data. Brush goes away!

[image: Delete unwanted brushes]

Comment: Hello, I can't find this panel, could you please be more specific or show a larger screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Put this together just now.  Hopefully this is more helpful!

Tool> Brush Manager> [image: Tool Brush Manager Path]